# Read numbers OCR using PowerShell in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, tesseract, imagemagick-convert

There are some pictures which have numbers and I would like to read these numbers. Here's my try till now

```
Public vCaptcha, bPowerShell

Sub Test()
    vCaptcha = CleanNumber(ScriptFile(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Number.png"))
    Debug.Print vCaptcha
End Sub

Function ScriptFile(strImage As String) As String
    Dim wshShell As Object, sFilePath As String, sOutput As String, strCommand As String
    sOutput = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\OutputNumber.txt"
    sFilePath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "\Desktop\CreateImage.ps1"
    If Dir(sFilePath) = "" Then GoTo Skipper
    strCommand = "Powershell.exe -File " & sFilePath & " " & strImage
    Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    wshShell.Run strCommand, 0, True
    On Error GoTo Skipper:
    ScriptFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(sOutput).ReadAll: Exit Function
Skipper:
    bPowerShell = True
    MsgBox "Run Create PowerShell File First", vbExclamation
End Function

Function CleanNumber(ByVal strText As String) As String
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "[^0-9]"
        If .Test(strText) Then
            CleanNumber = WorksheetFunction.Trim(.Replace(strText, vbNullString))
        Else
            CleanNumber = strText
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

The code works but returns wrong numbers or just one digit or two at most.
Here's the script Powershell code (CreateImage.ps1)

```
$image=$args[0]
$desktop= (Join-Path $env:USERPROFILE 'Desktop')
$imagefile=(Join-Path $desktop 'NumberNew.png')
$textfile=(Join-Path $desktop 'OutputNumber')

cd (Join-Path $desktop '\')
magick convert $image -resize 300x160 -density 300 -quality 100 $imagefile
magick convert $imagefile -negate -lat 300x160+40% -negate $imagefile
tesseract.exe $imagefile $textfile -l eng
```

Here's a sample of the image

[image]

Comment: So you've done some debugging to figure out at what point it's not working as you expect?  It's unclear what the exact problem is here.  Does (for example) tesseract have a problem with creating a correct interpretation of your image?  Or is it something else?

Comment: Yes, the problem is with reading the correct number on the image. It just returns the digit 7 from the image. I tried some combinations in the magick convert lines but with no use. So how can I improve the image more so as to get a correct result?

Comment: So then this is not a VBA question, but one about magick and tesseract....   If you fix your tags you might get some useful input.